# AWS SES Domain Verification not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to verify a domain on aws ses, the domain is managed on google domains. It has been three days since adding the text record in google domains, but still not getting verified in aws ses. I am not sure what could be problem. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me debug this issue.

Record Type: TXT (Text)
TXT Name*: _amazonses.xxxxxxx.com
TXT Value: fgfgghjjkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: That doesn't look like a real domain name. What is the domain name?

Comment: Domain names is mypyapps.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't created the TXT record that Amazon SES is looking for:

```
$ host -t txt _amazonses.mypyapps.com
Host _amazonses.mypyapps.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Rather, you created a different TXT record:

```
$ host -t txt _amazonses.mypyapps.com.mypyapps.com
_amazonses.mypyapps.com.mypyapps.com descriptive text "zFQacSiZbwXvc/4qJAjwHc8L3Wt6v6jMr/Ar/ac08Q4="
```

When you create your records, the domain name is automatically appended to whatever label you entered. So you do not need to repeat it.

Remove the extra labels when you create your TXT record. (And any other records you might have.)